# Serializing a process instance in Python

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I would like ot serialize a class object so that I can send it over a serial connection to another device.

The object looks something like this:

```
class runningprocesses(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.processes = WMI.InstanceOf('Win32_Process')
```

I am trying to serialize this using pickle and store it into a variable so that I can send it away, but whenever I try to pickle this object, I get an error. (Type Error: Can't pickle PyIDispatch objects)

```
myrunningprocesses = runningprocesses()
temp = pickle.dumps(myrunningprocesses)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to try `dill` or `cloudpickle`.  They are much better serializers than `pickle`.  However, I don't think either will work for your process object -- nor should they work for classes defined in C, unless those classes have a reduce method.  A decent trick is to capture the state of the object in a string or something else that can be pickled. You can often do that with subclassing/monkeypatching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some types in Python are inherently unserializable, and processes would certainly be one of those. Processes don't run in a vacuum - they have many properties such as the user identity or identities, open files, and so on. You can't put a wrapper around all these and then reconstitute them on demand.

You were being a little optimistic about `pickle`'s abilities.

Comment: I am running into this issue not only when I try to serialize Processes, but when I try to serialize other class objects as well. is it safe to say that one cannot pickle a class object?

If that is the case, what is the most efficient way for me to serialize this object in order to send it down a COM port?

Comment: Classes from extension modules (written in a compiled language like C) generally can't be pickled. Consider saving the object state in a pickle instead (the values of the variables needed to re-create it).